# Is it valid for css at-rule to be in style attribute?

Tags: html, css

Is the following markup valid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Test whether at-rules are valid in style attributes</title>
    </head>
    <body style="@import url(style.css);"></body>
</html>
```

Firefox and Chromium on Linux don't render it, but the W3C validator did not mark it as an error.

Comment: You cant import in inline style.

Comment: The W3C HTML validator does not validate CSS. It's not valid: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-style-attr/#syntax

Comment: If it doesn't work, who cares if it's valid or not?

Comment: The W3C validator is always experimental. It cannot handle all stupid attempts to overrule the standards.

Comment: The important part of the specification is "The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents of a CSS declaration block" -- `@import` would not be valid in a declaration block. So not only does it not work, is it not valid.

Comment: @Blender There's the W3C CSS validator. http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: @Pietu1998 ... which validates _CSS_ only.

Comment: @raina77ow — No. It says "Enter the URI of a document (HTML with CSS or CSS only) you would like validated"

Comment: The CSS validator, [given a suitable test document](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest-cases.dorward.me.uk%2Fstackoverflow%2F24717215%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en), will complain about incorrect properties and values, but ignores `@` rules. This appears to be a bug.

Comment: @Juhana, if we didnt cared about standards, why make standards anyway?

Comment: @davidkonrad Unless steve is developing a web browser, standards-compliant markup is meaningless if it doesn't work in browsers.

Comment: @Juhana, I disagree. hounoring the standards is the only way to be sure that your work will function all the the way, in any browser. There had been small differences, but over time they vanish. There are practically no difference between IE11 and Chrome.Opera or FireFox. Not in how the standards are interpreted.

Comment: @davidkonrad I agree completely, but I'm not saying "who cares if it's valid or not." I'm saying "**if it doesn't work,** who cares if it's valid or not." The question basically says "This code doesn't work. Is it valid?" when it should say "This code doesn't work. How to fix it?" Validity has no meaning *in the context of this question*.

Comment: @Juhana, allow me to clarify. Since I am working on a project that needs to parse HTML, I was curious to know if I would come across the situation in my question, and would need to handle it properly, since it would have added considerable complexity to my code.

Comment: That makes sense! Sorry about making assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Only a [declaration](http://pumpula.net/p/apps/css-vocabulary/#declaration) may be placed inside a style attribute.

From the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#adef-style):

> The syntax of the value of the style attribute is determined by the default style sheet language. For example, for [[CSS2]] inline style, use the declaration block syntax described in section 4.1.8 (without curly brace delimiters).

Comment: A newer reference (with the same principle stated): W3C Recommendation [CSS Style Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/).

Answer (score 2):

It is not.

`@`-rules can't contain rules directly, but only selectors.

- `@import` imports a file, but they can't have rules outside selectors.
- `@media` can only contain selectors.
- `@font-face` doesn't affect elements.

The `style` attribute is meant for setting rules *directly* to elements, so clearly the `@`-rules don't fit to that.